# Moving to IIS caused a repeater inside User-Control disappeared

Tags: asp.net, iis, user-controls, repeater

The project was working great as a Web Application
when I moved it to IIS the User Control's Repeater doesn't work anymore
and it is disappeared from the site

It was working great before moving to IIS

in the code behind

We have **FetchData**

```
...
                reapGallery.DataSource = pagedProducts;
                reapGallery.DataBind();
```

because the repeater is empty it never will be shown

The problem should be the security issues between IIS and SQL , Adding users or so

Comment: As I'm working with it I found that the problem is just in case of showing the repeater , this is not a path's issue ,, Any help is appreciated

Comment: Show your markup and your DB conn string?

Comment: The problem was confusing at first cause it was in a way that you thought it should be other problems, when I moved my site fromk web application to web address some of the relative addresses lead us to wrong locations and that caused me think that the user control which had a repeater also have an address issue and because of this it won't be shown, the problem at last was one of the repetitive daily tasks regarding IIS security, seems silly but I was in hurry and dealing with different projects/Situations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change paths to:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../Project/CSS/styleGallery.css" 
    type="text/css" media="screen">
<link rel="stylesheet" id="BxCss" href="../Project/CSS/cbox.css" 
    type="text/css" media="all">
<%@ Register Src="~/Project/CC/Gallery.ascx" TagPrefix="uc" TagName="Gallery" %>

<uc:Gallery runat="server" ID="iGallery" />
```

Comment: hi thanks for your answer, I'll check it out, but why other controls were working with the same address "~/CC/xx.ascx" ? and this one won't work ?

Comment: They obviously resolved correctly with the root (~/) operator - try making this control the same. Do not hard-code the paths. BTW, user controls do not generate a DLL...

Comment: It said : the path does not exist , the only working and probably true one is Src="~/cc/xx.ascx" as others , It won't give any errors , but I couldn't see the Repeater and the panels and it's page's Load event seems that never loaded

Comment: I did make a web application in the IIS, the problem topic is changed for me , this is not an addressing issue , it is about showing the repeater, if needed I could give more of the code , thanks again for your suggestions

Comment: Ok plz give me a minute , just as a guess , I have some doubts that maybe it caused by changing the page to HTML5, just maybe, I'll send parts of the code in minutes

Comment: Added the Code, also gave you +1 for your participation in this thread , hope you could help me , thanks

Comment: I got the problem and looking for the solution : the problem is DataTable productResults = ProductData.GetProoducts(...) returns null when the project moved to IIS and it should be because of the IIS-SQL Security and what is between , What should I do next ?

Comment: Hi again my friend, thanks for your participation in my issue, I solved it within those hours while I found the real issue point , It's a repetitive task to deal with the SQL logins and IIS and sometimes maybe we forget a part of it especially when dealing with different kid of projects , I know the question itself mislead it's audience , but anyway thanks and hope to see you again in SO